# rem in web component shadow dom

Tags: javascript, css, font-size, web-component, shadow-dom

We know that we can set `font-size` on `html` as the `rem` base in normal DOM nodes, and I use this trick to make my font of my app more flexible, dynamically changed with js.

However, when I created a web component, I found `rem` inside the shadow DOM always refers to 16px, even though I tried adding a style `*{ font-size:72px }` inside the shadow DOM. 16px is the common browser default font size.

Here's a simple demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/qmacwb6r/

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var template =`
<style>
* {
    font-size: 72px;
}
div {
    font-size:2rem;
}
</style>
<div>
    I am 2rem = 2*broser default
</div>
`
class TestTemplate extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.rt = this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
        this.rt.innerHTML = template;
    }
}
customElements.define("test-component", TestTemplate);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<test-component></test-component>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried calling `getRootNode()` in the console.

For normal DOM nodes, it returns HTMLElement, whereas for shadow DOM nodes, it returns ShadowRoot, which, unlike HTMLElement, cannot be styled.

Is it possible to make the rem base font of the nodes in shadow DOM variable and controllable?

Comment: [`rem` and `em` difference](https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/). Have you tried using `em`? See following [fiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/job4umx2/)

Comment: Insert `* {  font-size: 72px; }` in a style tag inside the `head` of your document or in a CSS file and your font-size will be based on 72px instead of 16px. Right now, your `style` tag is after the `body` and is not applied to it.

Comment: You may use em as @Mukyuu suggested

Comment: @Mukyuu thanks for your advise. It's a nice solution to use `em`, which refers to parentNode's font size, where we set up font-size to all shadow DOM nodes ahead. But I still want to know how to use rem and how to change root font, just like how we do it in normal DOM.

Comment: it's like in normal DOM as suggested by @Jake

Answer (score 14):

Unless I am missing something `rem` values are **always** based on the font-size set for the `<html>` tag like this:

```
html {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

With the above the size `1rem` is equal to `100px`.

Here is an example where I set the `font-size` for `html` to 4px. And then use `rem` values in the component.

```js
var template = `
<style>
:host, :root { font-size: 48px; }
.rem2 { font-size:2rem; }
.rem3 { font-size:3rem; }
</style>
<p>I am 48px Times</p>
<div class="rem2">I am 2rem = 2*browser default</div>
<div class="rem3">I am 3rem = 3*browser default</div>
`;

class TestTemplate extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.rt = this.attachShadow({mode:"open"});
    this.rt.innerHTML = template;
  }
}
customElements.define("test-component", TestTemplate);
```

```css
html {
  font: 4px Courier;
}

body {
 font: 24px Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div>Before</div>
<test-component></test-component>
<div>After</div>
```

Run this and then go look in the DevTools computed tab. You will see that:
 1. the font-size for the text `I am 2rem = 2*browser default` is only 8px
 2. the font-size for the text `I am 3rem = 3*browser default` is 12px;

The `font-size` for `body` and `:host` do not have any affect on the `rem` sizes. Only the `font-size` in the `<html>` tag does.