# Vuetify: changing font-size of :host does not change rem behaviour

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, web-component

I have a web-component made with Vue.js 2 and Vuetify. I noticed that Vuetify uses `rem` as unit for classes such as "text-h6".

When I compile the webcomponent and my  has `font-size: 16px` everything is fine:

[image]

The problem is that if the  has `font-size: 9px` (and being a web-component this is not something I can decide), the result is this:

[image]

So [I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245991/10140665) that I should add this code in the web-component:

```css
:root, :host {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

To make the rem refer to it, but it does not work, everything just refers to the `<html>` element.

This is more about my code:

vuetify.ts

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({});
```

WebComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app style="max-width: 440px">
      <v-main>
        <!-- some more stuff here -->
        <group-card />
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

import "@/plugins/api";
import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify";

import { VApp, VMain } from "vuetify/lib";
import GroupCard from "@/components/group-card/GroupCard.vue";

@Component({
  vuetify,
  components: {
    VApp,
    VMain,
    GroupCard,
  },
})
export default class PncGroupRegistration extends Vue {
  /* SOME MORE STUFF HERE */
}
</script>

<style>
@import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
</style>

<style>
/* This is because vuetify uses rem, so to make it behave everywhere the same I set the root font-size */
:host {
  font-size: 100px !important;
}

</style>
```

**EDIT:**

I received an answer that said that I should have used `!important`. Even with that it is not working.

This is a piece from the chrome dev-tools, where you can see that `<html>` has `font-size: 9px`, but in the `:host` it is overwritten with `font-size: 100px!important`.

[image]

The result I am still getting is this, in which the only non-valued-in-px values are "Group A" and the description.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I created [this Github repo](https://github.com/euberdeveloper/test-webcomponent-vuetify-issue) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `rem` is meant to ***always*** refer to the font size on the root element (in HTML documents, the `<html>` tag. That is exactly what it is meant to achieve.

Comment: If you look (or run the snipped) at the precedent answer, this is not true. For shadowed webcomponents, the root should be not the `<html>` tag. The problem is that in the case of Vue.js this is not happening.

Comment: Check [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245991/3744304). It's not about what is the root, it's about what `rem` refers to.

Comment: It is not a very similar question and the answer there is almost the same of the one that is already answered here. The point here is that with webcomponents it should work like that, but with the one I make with Vue.js it is not behaving like that.

I linked a github repo with a reproducition readme https://github.com/euberdeveloper/test-webcomponent-vuetify-issue

Comment: From that answer (and this backs what I commented): *The font-size for body and :host do not have any affect on the rem sizes. Only the font-size in the <html> tag does.*

Comment: Ok, it is true. If you look at the snipped below, just everything but "Fantastic" is different. This is because only "Fantastic" was specified in px, not rem.

Answer (score 0):

Global `font-size` has **higher** specificity than `:host`

The brute way is `!important`

But its better to add Elements and increase Specificity in other shadowDOM CSS than `:host`

```html
<style>
  *  {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>

<my-component></my-component>
<br>
<my-component important></my-component>

<script>
  window.customElements.define('my-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
          .innerHTML = `
          <style>
          :host{
           font-size:20px ${this.hasAttribute("important") ? "!important" : ""};
          }
          span { color: green; font-size:30px }
          </style>
          Hello <span>Fantastic</span> WebComponent`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is not a wc made with Vue 2 and vuetify.

I have also, edited the question, but I guarantee you that even with `!important" after font-size of :host it still is not working.

Comment: Then you have to find out why Vue does not behave like vanilla Web Components

Comment: I was hoping in someone that already knew it and posted an answer :)

Comment: Actually this answer shows that it is not possible doing what I want to do. The word "Fantastic" is still the same size outside and inside the webcomponent because the font-size is specified in px. The other parts of the phrase are different only because they are not specified in rem but inherited form the parent. If you add a font-size in rem, it will still refer to the <html> tag